# How to move labels from graph in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to move those labels from the graph (like Finance Info, Network Info) which are mixed into that graph. also, I want to add 0 in the center as a label.

[image: graph]

```
labels = df1.columns
stats = df1.loc[0, labels].values
angles = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, len(labels), endpoint=False)  # Set the angle
# close the plot
stats = np.concatenate((stats, [stats[0]]))
angles = np.concatenate((angles, [angles[0]]))

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
ax = fig2.add_subplot(111,projection='polar')  # Set polar axis
ax.plot(angles, stats, 'o-', linewidth=1,color='#b1282e')
ax.fill(angles, stats, alpha=0.70,color='#b1282e')  # Fulfill the area

ax.set_thetagrids(angles * 180 / np.pi, labels)  # Set the label for each axis
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55503584/matplotlib-polar-plot-tick-axis-label-position) might help. You may want to add a few lines of code to create an actually working [minimal *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814974/3944322